# Assertion Failed: No application initializer named 'store'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've upgraded ember-cli from 2.x.x to 3.1.2, and suddenly one of my initalizers throwing this assertion error: Assertion Failed: No application initializer named 'store'

I think there is an ordering problem, one of my initalizers trying to import store which hasn't already been initialized.

Tried `after: 'store'` and `after: 'ember-data'` property in initalizers but none of them worked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the code (or example code that also fails) for the initializer that you are trying to get working? `after: 'ember-data'` should work.

Comment: You may have a direct reference to the store initializer. This was deprecated in Ember Data 2.x and removed in Ember Data 3.0. See https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0181-deprecate-ember-data-initializers.md